# Zend_Db query for joining two tables

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, select, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:

user[id, name, username, password, role]

event[id, date, location, name]

participant[id, userId, eventId]

And I want to select all the events on which a given user participated. For this I have created an sql query which I tested and returned the desired result.

```
SELECT * FROM event
INNER JOIN participant ON participant.eventId = event.id
WHERE participant.userId = $id
```

After this I tried turning it into a zend request which should have worked according to other post from this site.

```
public function getEvents($id) 
{
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select();

    $select->from('event')
           ->joinInner('participant','participant.eventId = event.id')
           ->where('participant.userId = ?', $id);

    $res = $db->query($select)->fetchAll();
    return $res;
}
```

I'm using "PDO_MYSQL" as an adaptor and I don't have any problem with inserting into a table, selecting an entire table or just specific rows. But the above code seems to do a simple fatchall() insted of what I want. And whatever I try changing on it it always returns the event tables content.

My question is: Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: The code there doesn't do anything except construct the query.  can you post the code showing how you execute it and fetch the results?  I tried the query with your table structure and it worked fine.

Comment: @drew010 that's probably the root of my problem. I'm quite new to zend and also php. I'm learning from different tutorials I find and from the guide on the zend page. I'm forwarding my query to the view where I simply list it with a for. that's probably my problem. Could you pls tell me what I need to do to execute it? I've been searching the last 30 minutes for it but nothing worked so far.

Comment: @drew010 OK I just figured out what my problem was. I was calling a different method. Because I have a method called getAllEvents which has no parameters but I was calling it with a parameter, and it didn't throw any error or warning or anything. And I just saw it now. And with regards the execution and fetching of the results I modified my code a little and I hope it's going to be fine that way because for now it works.

Comment: In the meantime I posted an answer, didn't see you had figured it out.  Hopefully my answer proves helpful in addition to what you already know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

```
// this is the action in your controller
public function testAction()
{
    // call getEvents, assign the result to the view
    $this->view->results = $this->_getEvents(1);

}

protected function _getEvents($id)
{
    $db     = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select()
                 ->from('event')
                 ->joinInner('participant','participant.eventId = event.id')
                 ->where('participant.userId = ?', $id);

    //echo $select; // you can echo the select object to see the resulting query

    $results = $select->query(); // actually execute the query

    return $results->fetchAll(); // return all results as an array to caller
}
```

Then, here is some sample code to put in the view script:

```
<?php if (sizeof($this->results) == 0): ?>
<strong>No results found!</strong>
<?php else: ?>

Found <?php echo sizeof($this->results) ?> results.<br /><br />

<?php foreach($this->results as $result): ?>
    On <?php echo $result['date'] ?> the user participated in <em><?php echo $result['name'] ?></em> @ <?php echo $result['location'] ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Eventually when you become more familiar with ZF, you will want to create models and data mapper classes for fetching the data.  Your `getEvents` function would reside in a data mapper class.

Then following MVC separation, your controller would request the data from the data mapper which is responsible for communicating with the DB and processing the results.  The controller gets the data returned from the mapper and then assigns it to the view.  You would never want to be fetching data from the view, only displaying data that was given to it by the controller.

I have found the [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) to be very helpful when first starting out with ZF.  Just read it over one time and if you feel the need, go through it again and actually create the sample app so you can get a feel of it.  That was what I used to get started with ZF and it gave me a much better starting point with controllers and data mappers than I had previously.

Once you complete that guide, reading the reference guide is a lot easier and makes more sense as well.

Comment: It is useful. To bad I can't rate it. I also read the Quickstart and it has proven useful. But the problem was that after that I started a new projected and started learning the acl part and adding jquery(which didn't work out to well) I will probably have to look around on the forum to see if I found some solution to that problem as well. As a result I returned to add some basic functionalities and found myself lost in the code I have written. So now I started it from scratch and with the basics first, hopefully it will work out this way.